# Cascading - Group By field name issue

Tags: cascading

I am trying to read the file using Cascading and use Group By on specific field.

But its returning all the rows in the source file.

**Source File:**

```
no,date,amt
1,3/10/2016,1000
1,3/10/2016,2000
1,3/11/2016,400
232,2/10/2016,1500
```

**Code:**

```
Fields tscnFields = new Fields("no", "date", "amt");
FileTap tscnFileTap = new FileTap(new TextDelimited(tscnFields,true, ","),  "C://Users//Test//tscn.txt");

    final Fields groupField = new Fields("date");

    Pipe pipe = new Pipe("test"); 
    pipe = new Each(pipe, new Debug()); 
    pipe = new GroupBy("group by date", pipe, groupField); 
    Fields outFields = new Fields("no", "date", "amt");
    FileTap sinkTap = new FileTap(new TextDelimited(outFields,true, ","), "C://Users//Test//out.txt", SinkMode.REPLACE);         Flow flow = flowConnector.connect("FlowMonitorTest", tscnFileTap, sinkTap, pipe);
    flow.complete();
```

The output i am getting is

```
['1', '3/10/2016', '1000']
['1', '3/10/2016', '2000']
['1', '3/11/2016', '400']
['232', '2/10/2016', '1500']
tuples count: 4
```

Comment: what sort of output do you want?

Answer (score 1):

if you want an output like the one given below

```
date
2/10/2016
3/10/2016
3/10/2016
3/11/2016
```

Then you must check this code, which shall Group the tuples by Date and return the tuples with the date field only. Following is the code

```
import java.util.Properties;

import cascading.flow.Flow;
import cascading.flow.FlowDef;
import cascading.flow.local.LocalFlowConnector;
import cascading.operation.Debug;
import cascading.operation.Identity;
import cascading.pipe.Each;
import cascading.pipe.GroupBy;
import cascading.pipe.Pipe;
import cascading.property.AppProps;
import cascading.scheme.local.TextDelimited;
import cascading.tap.Tap;
import cascading.tap.local.FileTap;
import cascading.tuple.Fields;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tap sourceTap=new FileTap(new TextDelimited(true,","),
                "text");
        Tap sinkTap=new FileTap(new TextDelimited(true,","),
                "output");
        Pipe inputPipe=new Pipe("input_to_group");
        Fields groupField=new Fields("date");
        inputPipe=new Each(inputPipe,new Debug());
        inputPipe=new GroupBy(inputPipe,groupField);
        inputPipe=new Each(inputPipe,new Fields("date"),new Identity());
        Properties properties=new Properties();
        AppProps.setApplicationJarClass(properties, Main.class);
        FlowDef flowDef=FlowDef.flowDef().addSource(inputPipe, sourceTap)
                .addTailSink(inputPipe, sinkTap);
        Flow zodiacFlow=new LocalFlowConnector(properties).connect(flowDef);
        zodiacFlow.complete();
    }
}
```

Hope, this answer suffice your requirement!
Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Yes, obviously you get the same output as input.

You are grouping fields with a field **'date'** but doing nothing with the grouped field data so you are getting same input as output.

**What should be done:** In cascading after grouping data, we need to call **Buffer** to process that grouped data (**Buffer** calls in **Every** Assembly).

In above example, you grouped data with field **'date'** so following three groups will be the input for every **Buffer Operation**:

```
no,date,amt
1,3/10/2016,1000
1,3/10/2016,2000

no,date,amt
1,3/11/2016,400

no,date,amt
232,2/10/2016,1500
```

Now, with those input you can do your operation to change the input.

**Note:** In Hadoop Cascading each data operation is carried out in different distributed system. To make sure and carry out the operation at same machine we do the Buffer Operation (Grouping is needed for it).